# C# RemoveAll return value and count objects removed

Tags: c#, removeall

I am new to C# and I have a method that uses removeAll to remove objects from a list but I am not quite sure what the return value is. I have looked around but am struggling to find a definitive answer.

does the method return a value of 1 or 0 based on if an object was removed or does it return the number of objects removed? if it is just returning 1 or 0 how would i go about counting the number of objects that have been removed?

```
    public bool Remove(string name)
    {
        if (this.list.RemoveAll(x => x.Name.Equals(name)) == 1)
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Comment: I don't understand. what is going on in your markup??

Comment: This is surely documented by MS, just look it up.

Comment: I am passing a name to the method and it is removing all objects that have that name and then returns true of false depending if something was removed or not

Comment: A simple Google search "C# RemoveAll" would have redirect you to the [documentation page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a)

Comment: Also, you can evict the if, simply writing `return this.list.RemoveAll(x => x.Name.Equals(name)) == 1`

Comment: ''*The number of elements removed from the List<T> .*''

Comment: Thank you guys, I was looking at that page but i missed that part, sorry for being an idiot .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/wdka673a(v=vs.110).aspx) for List.RemoveAll()

> Return Value Type: System.Int32 The number of elements removed from
>   the List.

So you just can `return this.list.RemoveAll(x => x.Name.Equals(name))`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `list` is of type `List<string>`, note that the data structure can hold duplicates. To account for that, use the fact that the return value is the number of elements removed:

```
public bool Remove(string name)
{
    return this.list.RemoveAll(x => x.Name.Equals(name)) >= 1;
}
```